# Section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I try to set restarting section numbering in each chapter as well with the command.

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}
```

and get this:

> A. Introduction \\ 
>   A..1 Background

How to remove one of the dot after section numbering?

If I use the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\section{Combinatorics}
\subsection{Introduction}   
\subsection{Binomial Theorem}

\end{document}
```

the execution builds:

> A Combinatorics
>
> A.1 Introduction
>
> A.2 Binomial Theorem

But if I use other code:

```
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}
\section{Combinatorics}
\subsection{Introduction}   
\subsection{Binomial Theorem}

\end{document}
```

the result is:

> A. Combinatorics
>
> A..1 Introduction
>
> A..2 Binomial Theorem

I need the result:

> A. Combinatorics
>
> A.1. Introduction
>
> A.2. Binomial Theorem

Comment: Welcome, this depends on how you managed to get two dots there in the first place. Right now, your question is abit hard to understand, as you are talking of chapters and sections. Please post a compilable minimal working example.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Se! Pl. provide a MWE, for the same.

Comment: You might have `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\thesubsection}`, which should be `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\thesubsection}`. But this is a shot into the blue with a little help of my magic 8-ball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick hack:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\section{Combinatorics}
\subsection{Introduction}   
\subsection{Binomial Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good catch! Thank you very much for noticing!

Comment: I noticed *nothing* ;-)

Comment: @EnosLolang Please reconsider your choice of accepted answers, this one is (as a wrote) a quick hack, the much cleaner solution is the one of Christian Hupfer

Comment: Yes, thank you. actually I prefer that one, but the lack is the two lines syntax:  \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}  
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}

Answer (score 6):

Since any of the `\theX` (`X` meaning `section`, `subsection` etc down to `subparagraph` (?).) counter outputs should have a suffix `.`, the easiest way is to redefine `\@seccntformat` to have this trailing dot.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\section{Combinatorics}
\subsection{Introduction}   
\subsection{Binomial Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]